# Adding parameters to OPENQUERY SQL through an Excel cell

Tags: sql, excel, t-sql, openquery

I have a SQL query which works in Excel but it uses the following code.

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF

SELECT * 
FROM OPENQUERY (
    INSQL, 
    "SELECT DateTime = convert(nvarchar, DateTime, 21), [TagName]
     FROM WideHistory
     WHERE wwRetrievalMode = 'Cyclic'
           AND wwCycleCount = 100
           AND wwVersion = 'Latest'
           AND DateTime >= '20161122 08:33:00.000'
           AND DateTime <= '20161122 08:38:00.000'"
)
```

I am trying to add the `DateTime` through an Excel cell. Reading through forums, it mentioned that parametrizing `OPENQUERY` is not as straightforward as normal SQL queries in Excel.

Is there anything I can do to link a cell in Excel where I can change these parameters from?

Answer (score 1):

The docs: [OPENQUERY (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx):

> Syntax   OPENQUERY ( linked_server ,'query' ).  OPENQUERY does not
> accept variables for its arguments.
>
> ' query ' -Is the **query string**

Create query as string and execute

```
DECLARE @dt_start DATETIME = '2016-11-22 08:33:00.000';
DECLARE @dt_end DATETIME = '2016-11-22 08:38:00.000';

DECLARE @query VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @openquery VARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @query = 'SELECT DateTime = convert(nvarchar, DateTime, 21), [TagName]
                 FROM WideHistory
                 WHERE wwRetrievalMode = ''Cyclic''
                 AND wwCycleCount = 100
                 AND wwVersion = ''Latest''
                 AND DateTime >= ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), @dt_start, 121) + '''
                 AND DateTime <= ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), @dt_end, 121) + '''';

 --SELECT @query; 

SELECT @openquery = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY (INSQL, ''' + REPLACE(@query, '''', '''''') + ''')';

 --SELECT @openquery;

EXEC (@openquery);
```

Comment: The above query works but since I have little programming experience, can you please explain how to set @dt_start using VBA/Excel from an excel cell from a user's point of view. I don't want the user to have to go change the code. Thanks

Comment: This code should be inside store procedure. Stored procedures have ability to pass parameters.

Comment: dt_start DATETIME = '2016-11-22 08:33:00.000';
dt_end DATETIME = '2016-11-22 08:38:00.000';

Hard coded values were only for testing. 

Those variables should be stored procedure parameters. When you execute stored procedure from VBA, you can pass cells values as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql @openquery
```